# List size has unexpected value

Tags: java, list, indexoutofboundsexception

Suppose the following situation in a loop:

```
LinkedList<String> myList = someMethodReturnsList();
int start = 0, end = 0;

while (end < myList.size() && someOtherCondition)
    ++end;

List<String> subList = myList.sublist(start, end);

... (do stuff and possibly alter list)

start = end;
```

I'm having a situation where **only sometimes**, that call to `sublist` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Given my first test of `end < myList.size()`, this troubled me, so I wrote some debug code. My debug code told me that somewhere between that `while` loop and calling `sublist`, my `end` value ended up being 34 while `myList.size()` was returning 33.

How is that even possible? There are no other threads that can be operating on this list in my program, so how did my loop check pass and increment `end` to 34?

EDIT: this consistently happens at a particular point in my code's execution, so it's not a fluke error, but it doesn't happen with every input that this function has, which makes this even stranger.

Comment: The only logical explanation is that either someOtherCondition is modifying the List, or someMethodReturnsList is retaining a reference to the List and is modifying it.

Comment: Those both sound logical. However, `someMethodReturnsList` always makes a `new` instance, and `someOtherCondition` just checks a property (read only) from the `end`th element of `myList`.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to include the two?
And, by the way, `LinkedList` is definitely not a good class for doing `myList.get(end)` and `myList.subList`.

Comment: Are you sure the `end` value is 34 and not 33? Not to sound condescending or anything. Just saying that it would still throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if it were 33 :)

Comment: @JalithaDeSilva It shouldn't throw it if `end` were 33 according to the documentation of `List`. The second parameter of `List.sublist` is an *exclusive* last index. That said, it doesn't make any sense that `end` should ever be able to get the value of 34.

Comment: @2mac In that case, I'm very confused haha. Sorry I was under the impression that sublist used a zero-based index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I've figured it out through careful debugging.

Turns out, on the loop iteration where this exception occurs, the `end` value is **starting** at 34. Thus, the increment loop passes, and there is an index error.

The reason is that in the previous iteration, `myList.size()` was 36, but over the course of that loop, 3 elements were removed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is impossible.

Actually, the only way for this to happen is your own debugging: There are IDE features like code elements inspection that execute parts of the code while the application is paused on a breakpoint.

You have to be changing the value of `end` with the debugger tools.

Comment: I'm not using my debugger in this case. I'm aware that the situation I've described should not be possible. The only way it makes sense is if `myList.size()` is 34 during the loop and somehow decrements after it. That's why I came here; I don't understand how this could happen at all.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is along the lines of what @Jalitha said, off by one: the sublist call should be:

```
List<String> subList=myList.sublist(start,end-1);
```

The reason that you are sometimes getting the correct number probably has to do with your someOtherCondition.

Remember that size() is 1 more than the last index and subList works on indexes.

I would have put this in a comment but unable due to reputation :(

Comment: thanks for the pickup! Didn't realise, I feel a bit silly now :P I'll edit my answer as well.

Comment: Lol np, but it seems like it either didn't work for 2mac or it wasn't clear enough?

Comment: Disregard, I just saw the other comments and tried it out myself, using the size should work fine. I think we may need to see more of the actual code to figure this one out?

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me like a classic 'off-by-one' array error. You're likely having `end` equal to `myList.size()`, and then referencing one more ahead than you mean to. 
From your while loop for e.g. if array had 5 elements:

```
while (end < 5 && conditions)
{
   ++end; //results in end being 5
}
```

then later on it goes

```
List<String> subList = myList.sublist(0, 5);
```

and 5 is outside the bounds as the array only has indices 0,1,2,3,4

I think you should either make it `while (end+1 < 5 && conditions)` or `myList.sublist(0, end-1);`

**EDIT:** Props to @Justen, for pointing out my mistake.